# With a string longer than 10 letters, char* changes without any apparent reason. Why?

Tags: c++

In step 2 I change only the value of `name_C`. Why does `name_B` also change?

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
// step 1
        char *name_A;
        char *name_B;
        char *name_C;

        string str_L = "hello";
        string str_M = "stringVar_A";  ;

        name_A = (char *) str_M.c_str();  
        name_B = (char *) (str_L + "-car-" + str_M).c_str();
        name_C = (char *) str_L.c_str();

        cout << " name_A= " << name_A  << endl;
        cout << " name_B= " << name_B  << endl;
        cout << " name_C= " << name_C  << endl << endl << endl;

// step 2
        string str_N = "myStringMyString"; // (in my real code, i can't put this line in step 1)
        string str_R = "ABCDEFGHI" + str_N;   // (in my real code, i can't put this line in step 1)
        name_C = (char *)str_R.c_str();   // change only name_C

        cout << " name_A= " << name_A  << endl;
        cout << " name_B= " << name_B  << endl; // changed, why?
        cout << " name_C= " << name_C  << endl; // changed, ok.

        system("PAUSE");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    };
```

Here the output:

```
    (step 1:)
name_A= stringVar_A
name_B= hello-car-stringVar_A
name_C= hello

    (step 2:)
name_A= stringVar_A
name_B= ABCDEFGHImyStringMyString
name_C= ABCDEFGHImyStringMyString
```

With:

```
string str_N = "myString"; // in step 2...
```

`name_B` does not change.
Why does `name_B` change if `str_N` is longer than 10 letters?
Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: `name_B = (char *) (str_L + "-car-" + str_M).c_str();` is the first pronlem in your code. The pointer gets invalid immediately because the object is only temporary. ... Undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: Ask yourself where in memory each pointer is pointing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing undefined behaviour.

```
   name_B = (char *) (str_L + "-car-" + str_M).c_str();
```

you create a temoprary string from the result of std::string::operator + , extract the C-character array out of it, but then no-one really cathes the temporary string.

when a temporary is not caught by const reference - it is destroyed right away. the string destructor de-allocates the inner character array and invalidates  name_B.

so, this is undefined behaviour since you try to work with memory address that is no longer valid.

Answer (score 4):

The pointer returned by a call to `c_str` is **only** valid for as long as the corresponding `std::string` stays in scope and is unmodified.

The behaviour in accessing it beyond that is undefined.

For example, `(str_L + "-car-" + str_M).c_str();` is returning you the `c_str` of an *anonymous temporary*. It will be immediately invalid after the assignment. In your case, `name_B` is invalidated.

Also, don't cast away the `const char*` return of `c_str()`. It's `const` for a very good reason: you should not attempt to modify the string contents through that pointer.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns a pointer to an internal buffer of a `std::string` with the guarantee that:

- it points to a NUL-terminated string;
- the range [`c_str()`; `c_str() + size()`] is valid.

In your case, `name_B` points to an internal buffer of a *temporary* object `name_B = (str_L + "-car-" + str_M).c_str();` which will lead to an Undefined Behaviour when you'll try to use it.
When you make some modifications on your stack (you define two new `std::string`s), you probably alter the stack place where your `name_B` points to (since the memory reserved by your temporary has been freed).

If you really have to get old style C-strings from your `std::string`s, make sure:

- The pointer retrieved from `std::string::c_str()` is no longer used when the `std::string` is modified or destroyed,
- hence you don't call `std::string::c_str()` from a temporary.